# Spring-Data-Elasticsearch cannot connect to node after Search Guard enabled

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and Spring-Data-Elasticsearch to remotely connect to an Elasticsearch server. Everything was working fine before Search Guard is applied.

After Search Guard is enabled in server side, I got the exception

ERROR o.s.d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository - failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available

Moreover, the Elasticsearch said "Someone speaks transport plaintext instead of ssl, will close the channel".

Can anybody give some suggestion how to cope with this issue?

Comment: Have you find solution for this?

Comment: @LoneWolf No. I gave up using spring's elasticsearch libraries cuz I don't think it supports elasticsearch well.